# android api23 fine_location permission

Tags: android

i made an app that uses the LocationManager and google maps, i have the permission in the manifest for fine and coarse location and it works great on all API under 23.
i followed the instructions here:
["gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission for android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865445/gps-location-provider-requires-access-fine-location-permission-for-android-6-0)
in API 23 i need an on run permission, but somehow i cant, the compiler cant resolve fine location, here is the image.

[image]

Comment: Show your imports please

Comment: Try: 'android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'